# Restart Unicorn issue (capistrano)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, unicorn

I've got following settings in *deploy.rb* to restart my server:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && [ -e /proc/$(cat #{unicorn_pid}) ]; then kill -USR2     \`cat #{unicorn_pid}\`; else cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec unicorn -c #{unicorn_conf} -    E #{rails_env} -D; fi"
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work. I mean that command executes (it asks me the password and gives no errors), but all changes in config files are still ignored (i.e. number of worker processes or database settings).

Answer (score 18):

Maybe this is because of the way unicorn restarts. Not every worker is restarted immediately. This is to make it possible to have zero downtime and loose no requests. If you want to see your changes for sure, try to stop and then start your application instead. I have had to do this some times. Of course you will potentially loose some request.

The following tasks is what I use for restarting, stopping, and starting my unicorn server.

```
desc "Zero-downtime restart of Unicorn"
task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "kill -s USR2 `cat #{shared_path}/pids/unicorn.pid`"
end

desc "Start unicorn"
task :start, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "cd #{current_path} ; bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E production"
end

desc "Stop unicorn"
task :stop, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "kill -s QUIT `cat #{shared_path}/pids/unicorn.pid`"
end
```

Hope this helps you.

Maybe [this](http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn) article is of interest.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I'm running only 1 worker, so I guess it can't be that.

Answer (score 1):

see here my baby~
[Restarting Unicorn with USR2 doesn't seem to reload production.rb settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388074/restarting-unicorn-with-usr2-doesnt-seem-to-reload-production-rb-settings)

Keep in mind that: your working directory in unicorn.rb should be : /your/cap/directory/current

NOT be: File.expand_path("../..", FILE)

Because the unicorn and linux soft link forking error: soft link can not work well.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [capistrano-unicorn](https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn) a try, that's what I currently use with the default hooks mentioned below.

#### Setup

Add the library to your `Gemfile`:

`ruby
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano-unicorn', :require => false
end`

And load it into your deployment script `config/deploy.rb`:

`ruby
require 'capistrano-unicorn'`

Add unicorn restart task hook:

`ruby
after 'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:reload'    # app IS NOT preloaded
after 'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:restart'   # app preloaded
after 'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:duplicate' # before_fork hook implemented (zero downtime deployments)`